# Where can you get the second and third parts of Fire Breath?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am having trouble finding the second and last parts of Fire Breath in Skyrim. I have searched everywhere for them, but I still can't find them. Where are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the UESP Wiki's "[Fire Breath](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fire_Breath)" article, the second is in [Sunderstone Gorge](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sunderstone_Gorge) and the final word is learned on the [Throat of the World](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Throat_of_the_World), during the quest "[Throat Of The World](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Throat_of_the_World)". Hope that helped.

Comment: Congrats on your first post! Remember to add the link where you got this information so Samuel can look thru it and for an even better answer add photos (mini map) and any extra information just in case the wiki get taken offline.

Comment: How do I get the quest for it

Comment: It's a story quest.